# Expand the events pane on calendar list view?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, calendar

I have built a list and have set it to use the Calendar view. I understand that I am unable to expand the additional "+3" events in the calendar, but I would like to be able to expand the events pane on the right side that shows all events listed for that day.

As you can see, the "2:00 customer presentation.." gets cut off in the default view. Is there any JSON or other suggested method that I can use to format the event pane to expand and show the entire title of the calendar event?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot of event title cut off]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to customize the events pane in [SharePoint online modern experience calendar list view](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/14/create-a-modern-calendar-view-in-sharepoint-online-microsoft-lists/).

However, you can hover on the event title to see the entire title of the calendar event:

[image]

---

**OR**:

Double click on the event from events pane to open the display form of calendar event:

[image]